# Catel examples crashing with System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: wpf, catel

I am unable to run the WPF examples and the Application error log is showing a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.

I have done a clean and rebuild but still get the error.
I'm assuming this is something basic as it is happening with all the WPF examples.
Any ideas?

Cheers
Geoff

```
Application: Catel.Examples.WPF.MasterDetail.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri)
   at Catel.Examples.WPF.MasterDetail.App.InitializeComponent()
   at Catel.Examples.WPF.MasterDetail.App.Main()
```

Appears to be some mismatch between latest version and previous one I have installed. Not sure what.

Exited Visual Studio 2013, loaded earlier version (3.9) of examples and got asked to update NuGet references which I did. Ran some examples. Exited VS.

Re-ran the NuGet script which told me everything was up to date.
Re opened latest examples in VS and ran Catel.Examples.WPF.MasterDetail which eventually loads but only if I pause the debugger and then 'continue'

If I run either the earlier or latest examples from the build it crashes.

Most peculiar.

I have also discovered that there are two errors in the log. One is the .Net runtime error mentioned above.
The second is an application error

```
Faulting application name: Catel.Examples.WPF.MasterDetail.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x542235b4
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18409, time stamp: 0x5315a05a
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000940d
Faulting process id: 0x1fec
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfd7a4db30449c
Faulting application path: H:\Frameworks\Catel\catelexamples-e5397fd24414\catelexamples_e5397fd24414\src\Catel.Examples.WPF.MasterDetail\obj\Debug\Catel.Examples.WPF.MasterDetail.exe
Faulting module path: G:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 190e501e-4398-11e4-a86f-005056c00008
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested this, and it works on my machine. I have updated all NuGet packages to the latest version and pushed that, maybe you can retry.

The WPF examples are .NET 4.5, make sure you have that installed (but this is probably already the case otherwise you couldn't have ran the examples in the first place).

Comment: Hi Geert. Thanks for your reply. Downloaded the latest zip from https://github.com/Catel/Catel.Examples but am still getting the problem. Note, on rebuilding the examples solution it I also updated the all the NuGet packages. Also am getting 4 compile errors in Catel.Examples.SL.DisplayProgress -> MainWindowViewModel.cs

Comment: You need the Silverlight toolkit for the SL samples to compile. But the WPF also fail to work? What vs version? What .net version?

Comment: Examples are .net 4.5

Comment: Apologies was looking at wrong set. Latest examples are unchanged and in .Net 4.5.

Comment: Have figured out what was going wrong. Was using obj/{proj}.exe. Projects have output path set to non-existent folder outside of project and were not building. When I set to bin/Debug - bin /Release the build and run. Am still getting errors on SL.DisplayProgress with

_splashScreenService.CommitAsync(progressControlViewModel, this, string.Format("ProgressRegion{0}", (click++) % 2));